# Как правильно править вопросы?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, статус-завершено

Предлагаю обсудить, что именно требует правки, на какие моменты нужно обращать внимание, внося правку.

Для начала - о приветствиях. Я считаю, что приветствия создают ненужный информационный шум и удаляю их. Основание для такого подхода - в правилах сайта:

"Вопрос — ответ. Ничего лишнего" (https://rus.stackexchange.com/tour)
"Не используйте подписи, статусы и приветствия" (https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/behavior)

Некоторое время тому назад, выяснилось, что не все согласны с таким подходом ("Вы только изничтожили хорошее слово "здравствуйте", которое никому не мешало")

Если мы придерживаемся этого подхода, хотелось бы попросить администраторов добавить слова ""Не используйте подписи, статусы и приветствия" в раздел "Как задавать вопросы". А если нет, то удалить их из всех разделов.

Comment: Я помню этот вопрос: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/432709/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%A1%D0%9F%D0%9F#comment437680_432709 . Но! - зря Вы вынесли ситуацию на всеобщее обозрение. Просто для хорошей правки мне потребовалось определенное количество времени и определенное количество мозгов: я старалась. А Ваша правка заключалась ТОЛЬКО в изничтожении "здравствуйте". Мне стало просто мало-мало обидно. Пнули бы мне камушек в комментарии - и всё! Я - тётка понятливая.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я сделал следующее добавление в статью ["Как задать хороший вопрос"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask):

> Пожалуйста, не используйте приветствия и подписи — это лишь усложняет восприятие информации.

М_Г, большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Действительно, при создании вопросов и ответов не рекомендуется использовать приветствия. Следовательно, при редактуре нужно их удалять — в сообщениях на сайте не должно быть ничего лишнего.

Вы нашли и привели нужные статьи. Совершенно верно! Участникам, которые не знакомы с ними, нужно давать соответствующие ссылки. Если вы столкнулись с "войной правок" (то есть кто-то бесконечно откатывает/изменяет вашу правку), обязательно привлеките внимание модератора к сообщению через кнопку "тревога".

Пожалуйста, уточните ваше предложение: в какую именно статью раздела ["Как задавать вопросы"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/asking) вы хотели бы добавить приведенные слова?

Comment: Ниболее подходящее, место: Справка > Как задавать вопросы > Как задать хороший вопрос > Будьте точны. Это место не идеальное, так как заявленная цель статьи: "как увеличить шансы на получение ответа". Но это лучшее из того, что есть. Ведь можно сказать, что делая вопрос более лаконичным, мы тем самым  увеличиваем  шансы на получение ответа.

Comment: @М_Г спасибо. Я постараюсь внести изменения в ближайшее время.